# How do you enable the escape key close functionality in a Twitter Bootstrap modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I followed the instructions for the [Twitter Bootstrap modal on their main documentation page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) 
 and used the `data-keyboard="true"` syntax mentioned but the escape key does not close the modal window.
  Is there something else I'm missing?

Code:

```
<a href="#my-modal" data-keyboard="true" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal</a>

<div class='modal fade hide' id='my-modal'>
  <div class='modal-body'>
    <div>Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is enabled by default

Answer (score 334, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue with how the keyup event is being bound.

You can add the `tabindex` attribute to you modal to get around this issue:

```
tabindex="-1"
```

So your full code should look like this:

```
<a href="#my-modal" data-keyboard="true" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal</a>

<div class='modal fade hide' id='my-modal' tabindex='-1'>
    <div class='modal-body'>
    <div>Test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For more info you can view the discussion on [this issue on github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4663)

(Updated link to new TWBS repository)

Comment: This though prevents autofocus from input fields.

Comment: You can also append data-keyboard attribute to your div.modal (and omit it in callers) if you invoke the dialog from multiple places.

Comment: As @nrek points out below - close with escape is true by default, so you don't strictly need `data-keyboard="true"` - it's `tabindex="-1"` that enables the behaviour

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works in Bootstrap 4. I don't know why it doesn't work by default as the docs say.

Comment: Moreover, `data-keyboard` belongs on the modal element, not the controller. This can be tested by setting it to `false`.

Answer (score 25):

also if you're invoking via javascript , use this:

```
$('#myModal').modal({keyboard: true})
```

Comment: this used to be the only thing you had to do, but now you also need to make sure that your div has a 'tabindex="-1"' attribute.

Comment: I only had to set the tab index.

Comment: @dchacke that's because keyboard property is default to true! so just set tabindex='-1'

Answer (score 17):

add `tabindex="-1"` attribute to modal div

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In Angular I do it like this:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({                        
 keyboard: false,
 backdrop: 'static',
 templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/view/currentlyIneligibleView.html',
 controller: 'currentlyIneligibleCtrl',
 resolve: {
     data: function () { return param; }
    }
});
```

- `backdrop: 'static'` => Stop to close on clicking outside
- `keyboard: false` => Stop to close by using escape button

Answer (score 0):

let modals = []

```
        $(document).keyup(function(e) {
            if((e.key=='Escape' || e.key=='Esc' || e.keyCode==27) && modals.length) {
                $(".modal[modal='" + modals.pop() + "']").modal('hide')
            }
        })
        
        $(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal", e => {
            const id = modals.length
            modals.push(id)
            $(e.target).attr("modal", id)
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

## Bootstrap 3

In HTML, just set `data-backdrop` to static and `data-keyboard` to false

### Example :

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Launch modal</button>
```

or

```
$('#myModal').modal({
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: false
})
```

### Live Test :

https://jsfiddle.net/sztx8qtz/

Know More : http://budiirawan.com/prevent-bootstrap-modal-closing/

Comment: Your example doesn't enable escape key