# Trigger JavaScript action with keypress

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

**2020 update:**

I have a modal that closes with the code `modal.style.display = "none";`. How can I, using JavaScript, trigger the above code when the user presses `"ESC"` on their keyboard?

**Original question:**

> As the title says. Here is the modal code I'm using: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal2

Comment: You should really check for existing [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630156/how-do-you-enable-the-escape-key-close-functionality-in-a-twitter-bootstrap-moda) before you ask the community.

Comment: Please read **[ask]** and include relevant code *in the question*.  Links are fine but only if the question is valid without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your javascript code :

```
window.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```