# Binding data-dismiss="modal" to a key click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a simple modal that uses buttons to close it. The data-dismiss="modal" is binding to the button and it works perfectly fine.

I would like to bind the same functionality to my escape key and I'm wondering if its possible.

I tried something like the below but it does not work.

```
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {

        if (e.which == 27) {
          $('#postcard-items-modal').modal('data-dismiss');
        }

    });
```

If anyone can shed some light on this that would be great.

I know I can add classes to hide the model or add a style tag to close it but im specifically looking to bind the data-dismiss to run when escape is pressed.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate question, answer can be found, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630156/how-do-you-enable-the-escape-key-close-functionality-in-a-twitter-bootstrap-moda

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

**The Answer:**

So I didn't need any javascript to bind a keyclick.

Add I had to do was add tabindex='-1' to my modal id

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="PostcardModal" tabindex='-1'></div>
```

This will enable the escape button to close the modal.

Thank you to cmprogram.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `e.keyCode` instead of `e.which`? Or you can try e.key